# Magnetic field expression in a rectangular waveguide

Tags: rf, electromagnetism, electromagnetic, microwave, wave

I was reading the chapter of Fundations of Microwave Engineering (Robert E. Collin) about transmission lines and waveguides, and I have a question about the electromagnetic field in a **rectangular waveguide**.

Precisely, it consider a generic TE[m,n] mode and it gets the following equation for the magnetic field along z axis (propagation axis):

[image]

If we multiply that quantity by the function Zh(z) = P+ * exp(-kz) - P- * exp(kz), which represents the direct and reverse travelling waves, we get the total magnetic field component along z axis, with P+ and P- determined by the excitation power.

Then it says that *The constant Anm is an arbitrary amplitude constant associated with the nm-th mode*.

What does it mean? Has it a precise general value for each mode? For instance, which is its value for TE[1,0]?

Here the complete proof of that equation:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anm, the amplitude of each mode depends on the source, excitation of the waveguide and end conditions (and possibly obstacles in the guide). The author solves the differential equations for traveling waves in a hollow rectangular waveguide to find their general form without reference to the aforementioned factors.

The other book by the same author, 'Field theory of guided waves', deals with some specific problems (excitation of waveguides) and supplies formulas for the amplitudes of modes.